# filter list dynamically for each list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple filter list and I want above of them to put an input search filter, how I can filter lists for each list instead of multiply the code to make functions for each list, I will put what I tried:

```
function FilterPret() {
// Declare variables
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById('pretfilter');
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("filter-ul-pret");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("label")[0];
  txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
  if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

[image: filters img]

So instead of making 9 functions above for each filter list i wanted to make 1 because is those filters are dinamically from back-end.

Update: Html

```
<aside class="sidebar-tag filter tags shop by price ">
  <div class="widget">
     <h4>
      <span>Duritate </span>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clear" style="display:none">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </a>
    </h4>
 <div class="widget-content">
  <input type="text" id="duritatefilter" class="myfilterinput" onkeyup="FilterPret()" placeholder="Cauta duritatea">
 <ul class="scroll-basic">
  <li><label for="val1">
   <input type="checkbox" id="val1" value="100-300"><span>Moale</span></label>
  </li>
  <li><label for="val1"><input type="checkbox" id="val1" value="100-300">
      <span>Mediu</span></label>
  </li>
  <li><label for="val1"><input type="checkbox" id="val1" value="100-300">
   <span>Tare</span>  </label>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be possible, but we need to see your HTML in order to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use different `id` for every `ul` and pass that as argument to `FilterPret()` function on keyup event. Then instead of static value `filter-ul-pret` pass that `id` and collect list items.

Comment: And thats mean i need to make function for each id because i can`t have multiple id's on page, right?

Comment: There is no restriction to have multiple ID in one page. The value of ID attribute will be different. If you have problem setting ID you can use any other attribute even custom attribute like `data-someName` and use it for uniquely identify the `ul`

Comment: This is the reason for which i am posting this problem, i wanted to be with event targeting to search on child ul and filter li from ul dynamically without using an id because i have multiples fields with filtering. Thank you.

Comment: @Edward This is not the approach to use as you'll end up having to duplicate the code for each `id`. Use a common class and genericise the behaviour. As I said in the comments under the question, we can give you an example of how to do this, but we need to see your HTML.

Comment: You have the html is below of image.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you see the html what i posted under image?